# Equivalence Regular Smooth Point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let be $C \subset \mathbb{A}^2 _k$ a smooth  curve over **algebraically closed field** $k$ defined by a polynomial $f \in k[x,y]$, so $C= V(f)$.

A point $c \in C$ is called **smooth** if $\partial_x f$ and $\partial_y f$ aren't both zero.

Futhermore, $c \in C$ is called a **regular** point, if $dim \mathcal{O}_{C,c} = dim_{k(c)} m_c / m_c^2$ holds.

I heard that if $k$ is algebraically closed for a point smoothness and beeing regular is equivalent. Why? Does anybody has a good source for the proof?

Comment: [Mumford-Oda](https://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Geometry-Texts-Readings-Mathematics/dp/9380250800), page 227.